# Accessing a non-Public Google Sites page using curl + Bearer Token

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-sites, bearer-token

I need to access non-Public Google Site using Curl. Is it possible to GET a Google Site page using curl and sending in Bearer Token as part of the Authorization header?

I usually do this with Spreadsheets. But can't get it to work with Google Sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible currently with the new Google Sites. Google doesn't provide an API for this.